# Standardized Regression Coefficients for categorical interactions: lm.beta() vs. regressing standardized variables

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, lm

I am working with a regression model from which I would like to compute standardized regression coefficients.  I am writing primarily regarding an observed discrepancy between coefficients obtained by standardizing the variables before regressing and those computed using lm.beta().  In the former case, I regress scaled variables (using scale()) and obtain the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = correct.sc ~ P1_PO8_PatD.sc + P1_PO8_Third.sc + 
    P3a_FC1_D.sc + P3a_FC1_PatT.sc + P3a_FC1_Third.sc + P3b_CP1_T.sc + 
    P3b_CP1_PatT.sc + dx:P1_PO8_PatD.sc)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.77325 -0.45863 -0.05418  0.50733  2.10668 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                0.06382    0.10936   0.584  0.56161   
P1_PO8_PatD.sc            -0.25313    0.17836  -1.419  0.16084   
P1_PO8_Third.sc            0.32583    0.12458   2.615  0.01118 * 
P3a_FC1_D.sc              -0.63229    0.31296  -2.020  0.04768 * 
P3a_FC1_PatT.sc           -0.73578    0.25622  -2.872  0.00558 **
P3a_FC1_Third.sc           1.15503    0.43505   2.655  0.01007 * 
P3b_CP1_T.sc               0.38482    0.18897   2.036  0.04598 * 
P3b_CP1_PatT.sc           -0.24783    0.17129  -1.447  0.15299   
P1_PO8_PatD.sc:dxPROBAND   0.60647    0.33286   1.822  0.07328 . 
P1_PO8_PatD.sc:dxRELATIVE  0.03085    0.25768   0.120  0.90509   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8746 on 62 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.332, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2351 
F-statistic: 3.424 on 9 and 62 DF,  p-value: 0.001782
```

Using lm.beta(), I obtain the following:

```
> lm.beta(mod.complete)
           P1_PO8_PatD           P1_PO8_Third              P3a_FC1_D 
           -0.25313301             0.32583258            -0.63228654 
          P3a_FC1_PatT          P3a_FC1_Third              P3b_CP1_T 
           -0.73578305             1.15502579             0.38482487 
          P3b_CP1_PatT  P1_PO8_PatD:dxPROBAND P1_PO8_PatD:dxRELATIVE 
           -0.24782599             0.33812822             0.03085196 
Warning message:
In b * sx : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The discrepancy, then, comes for the coefficients associated with the interaction terms (where P1_PO8_PatD is a continuous variable and Dx is a categorical variable).  I believe I understand why this discrepancy arises--namely, lm.beta() likely uses the SD for the Dx-subsetted P1_PO8_PatD (and hence the warning)--but I am primarily wondering which is more "correct."  My inkling is to lean towards those obtained from the regression model using the scaled variables, but I can convince myself to go either way; any input would be much appreciated.

I didn't feel this example needed accompanying data, but I can provide it if desired.